# Numerical Differentiation

Tags: c, numerical-methods, numerical

How can I calculate the numerical second derivative of a function involving an exponential and a singularity at infinity. Unfortunately, the numerical derivative by Ridder's methods provided in "Numerical Recipes in C" can only calculate the first derivative (It requires analytical expression of the function beforehand.) Furthermore I have tried Chebyshev approximation and differentiating the function afterwards but the values given were way off the actual values. I have also tried some finite difference algorithms provided in a mathematical paper yet they were error prone too. The function is e^(x/2) / x^2. I would appreciate any help on the matter.

Thanks in advance

Latest Edit: The issue was solved the FADBAD libraries available in C++ did an extremely good job. They are available via http://www.fadbad.com/fadbad.html

EDIT:

```
// The compilation command used is given below
// gcc Q3.c nrutil.c DFRIDR.c -lm -o Q3

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "nr.h"

#define LIM1 20.0
#define a -5.0
#define b 5.0
#define pre 100.0 // This defines the pre
/* This file calculates the func at given points, makes a 
 * plot. It also calculates the maximum and minimum of the func
 * at given points and its first and second numerical derivative.
*/
float func(float x)
{
    return exp(x / 2) / pow(x, 2);
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("Q3data.dat", "w+"), *fp2 = fopen("Q3results.dat", "w+");
    int i; // Declaring our loop variable
    float x, y, min, max, err, nd1, nd2;
    // Define the initial value of the func to be the minimum
    min = func(0); 
    for(i = 0; x < LIM1 ; i++)
    {   
        x = i / pre; // There is a singularity at x = 0 
        y = func(x);
        if(y < min)
            min = y;
        fprintf(fp, "%f \t %f \n", x, y);
    }
    fprintf(fp, "\n\n");
    max = 0;
    for(i = 0, x = a; x < b; i++)
    {   
        x = a + i / pre;
        y = func(x);
        nd1 = dfridr(func, x, 0.1, &err); 
        //nd2 = dfridr((*func), x, 0.1, &err);
        fprintf(fp, "%f \t %f \t %f \t %f \n", x, y, nd1);
        if(y > max)
            max = y;
    }

    fprintf(fp2, "The minimum value of f(x) is %f when x is between 0 and 20. \n", min);
    fprintf(fp2, "The maximum value of f(x) is %f when x is between -5 and 5. \n", max);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Chebyshev

```
// The compilation command used is given below
//gcc Q3.c nrutil.c CHEBEV.c CHEBFT.c CHDER.c -lm -o Q3


#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "nr.h"
#define NVAL 150 // Degree of Chebyshev polynomial
#define LIM1 20.0
#define a -5.0
#define b 5.0
#define pre 100.0 // This defines the pre
/* This file calculates the func at given points, makes a 
 * plot. It also calculates the maximum and minimum of the func
 * at given points and its first and second numerical derivative.
*/
float func(float x)
{
    return exp(x / 2) / pow(x, 2);
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("Q3data.dat", "w+"), *fp2 = fopen("Q3results.dat", "w+");
    int i; // Declaring our loop variable
    float x, y, min, max;
    float nd1, nd2, c[NVAL], cder[NVAL], cder2[NVAL];
    // Define the initial value of the func to be the minimum
    min = func(0); 

    for(i = 0; x < LIM1 ; i++)
    {   
        x = i / pre; // There is a singularity at x = 0 
        y = func(x);
        if(y < min)
            min = y;
        fprintf(fp, "%f \t %f \n", x, y);
    }
    fprintf(fp, "\n\n");
    max = 0;
    // We make a Chebyshev approximation to our function our interval of interest 
    // The purpose is to calculate the derivatives easily
    chebft(a,b,c,NVAL,func);
    //Evaluate the derivatives
    chder(a,b,c,cder,NVAL); // First order derivative
    chder(a,b,cder,cder2,NVAL); // Second order derivative
    for(i = 0, x = a; x < b; i++)
    {   
        x = a + i / pre;
        y = func(x);
        nd1 = chebev(a,b,cder,NVAL,x);
        nd2 = chebev(a,b,cder2,NVAL,x);

        fprintf(fp, "%f \t %f \t %f \t %f  \n", x, y, nd1, nd2);
        if(y > max)
            max = y;
    }

    fprintf(fp2, "The minimum value of f(x) is %f when x is between 0 and 20. \n", min);
    fprintf(fp2, "The maximum value of f(x) is %f when x is between -5 and 5. \n", max);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics

Comment: @ChrisLaplante I asked it in numerical-methods category, I think that is pretty relevant.

Comment: Showing what you have done via Chebyshev approximation or  finite difference would be useful.  The algorithms may be sound, but your coding may be a concern and SO could help there.

Comment: @chux I have used the routines of numerical recipes anyways I will post the code without disclosing these routines since they are copyrighted.

Comment: @chux I have deleted my implementation of finite difference algorithms after I got a large amount of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That function is differentiable so using a numeric method is likely not the best.  The second derivative is:

6*exp(x/2)/(x^4)-2*exp(x/2)/x^3 + exp(x/2)/(4*x^2)

The above can be simplified of course to speed up computation.  Edit: had original formula wrong the first time.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that is differentiable analytically but the point is using an algorithm to work out the second derivative without aiding the computer analytically anywhere. Can it be done?

Comment: Yes, it can definitely be done.  I assume you have tried a few recipes and they do not work, without knowing exactly what you are trying to use, it would be hard to comment on what is failing.

Comment: As a note though, in general code to find dervatives is very buggy when most of us write it, always check the result of the derivative by using a finite difference approximation of the original function (1e-6 is a great value to use as the delta-X).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I have been consulting routines from Numerical Recipes book and I managed to calculate the second derivative with the aid of the first derivative evaluated at various grid points. I benefitted from a mathematics article on finite difference methods to write the algorith.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a 100% numeric approach then look at the [numerical recipes](http://www.nrbook.com/a/bookcpdf.php) for a cublic spline interpolation (Charter 3.3). It will give you the 2rd derivative at any location.

call `spline()` with `x` and `y` values to return the 2nd derivatives in `y2`. The second derivative varies linearly within each interval. So if for example you have

```
x      y      y2
0     10     -30
2      5     -15
4     -5     -10
```

then the 2nd derivative at `x=1` is `y2=-22.5` which is in-between -30 and -15.

you can also make a new `splint()` function to return the 2nd derivative  `a*y2a[i]+b*y2a[i+1]`

Comment: Unfortunately this approach yielded inf as the result at all the grid points involved. I actually referred to Ridders' method of polynomial extrapolation (Section 5.7). It worked fine for the first derivative and I was able to optimize it after reading the chapter, yet it requires the analytic expression for the function to be able to calculate the derivative as I mentioned. Later I combined this method with finite difference method to calculate the second derivative from first derivative evaluated by Ridders' method.